# Windows Universal App having to deploy before debugging

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

If I make any changes to my Windows Universal App I have to manually deploy it before I'm able to debug. By that I mean the breakpoints won't be hit because it's out of sync with the symbols.

I have Visual Studio 2015 with all the latest updates.

Is this by design?

Is there anyway to force a deploy before doing a debug?

Comment: Just started working on my first Universal App (for Win10 IOT Core), and hit this.  I can't imagine this has been the MO for the last several years...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can control which applications/projects are deployed in the configuration manager. Open the "configuration manager" from the "build" menu and check that your app is selected to be deployed.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Comment: On mine deploy was ticked but build not.... Anyway having them both ticked resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: My two cents, I had this problem today (Monday) at work but both Build and Deploy were ticked.
Then I noticed that the last thing I had done on Friday was create a version for release not for Debug, so make sure you are targeting the proper configuration also.